# @types/react-native for react-native 0.59.x

Tags: typescript, react-native, definitelytyped

I'm using `react-native 0.59.9` (can't yet upgrade to `0.60.x` because of external blockers).

But the `@types/react-native` only provides type-definitions up to `0.57.65` ([as listed in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-native)). From then on the versions jump straight to `0.60.x`. The first line in `index.d.ts` also tells me that the types in `@types/react-native 0.57.65` only support the `0.57` version:

```
// Type definitions for react-native 0.57
```

I have actually been using `@types/react-native 0.57.65` without problems so far with the `react-native 0.59`. But now that I'm having some problems, I'm starting to wonder whether this combination is even supposed to work.

Questions I'm pondering:

- Why are there no `0.58` and `0.59` releases of `@types/react-native`?
- Should I expect problems when using `react-native 0.59` with types for `0.57`?
- Is there a way around this besides upgrading to `0.60`?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Don't remember.